# EF Core FromSql issue

Tags: .net, ubuntu, asp.net-core

.net core sends different queries to database. It works in windows but in ubuntu, select all data, then filters.

Where am i doing wrong?

```
var query1 = pdb.WorkOrder.FromSql("SELECT * FROM WorkOrder");
var list = query1.Where(i => i.StartDate > DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

**RUNNING WINDOWS**

**SQL PROFILER RESULT**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
    dbo.WorkOrder
WHERE 
    StartDate > GETDATE()
```

**RUNNING UBUNTU**

**SQL PROFILER RESULT**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
    dbo.WorkOrder
```

Version: .net core 2.2

Comment: Who is the database provider on Ubuntu?

Comment: Same code running. Just install .net core and run dotnet blabla.dll @ΩmegaMan

Comment: Does the same happen with a call to `FromSqlRaw` if you put the where in that?

Comment: There is no `FromSqlRaw ` in this version @ΩmegaMan

Comment: Why not try v3.1? [Ubuntu 18.04 Package Manager - Install .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1804) … and try with that version. ?

Comment: I tried but same result. @ΩmegaMan